# Mongoose js: how to remove multiple sub docs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to remove sub-docs from collection

```
tasks = item.tasks; // item is mongodb collection element, tasks is array of sub docs

tasks.forEach(function(task){
if (!task.finished)
     tasks.remove(task)
})

item.save()
```

after that I get situation when not all sub-docs with finished==true are removed.

Is there the other more correct way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this atomically using an `update` with the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/#_S_pull) operator:

```js
Items.update({_id: item._id}, {$pull: {tasks: {finished: true}}}, ...);
```

Seems you could also do this with [`MongooseArray#pull`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-pull) but the docs on that are so thin I've never figured out how to use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Actually I made out how to use MongoseArray.pull, it takes list of objects (not array but list), so if you have array of tasks that you just call it using apply: tasks.pull.apply(tasks, tasks.some(function(task){return task.finished})